# How to create the an ajax call to return spConfig json with product sku (product options)

Tags: product, configurable-product

I'm using Varnish on my magento build and I want to Ajax the product options.

I've noticed that there is a json line in spConfig on the product page.

How would I go about creating a php ajax call e.g.

localhost/get_json_options.php

```
<?php

echo $this->getJsonConfig($sku / $product_id);

?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Put this content in your php file:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL | E_STRICT);
$mageFilename = 'app/Mage.php';
require_once $mageFilename;
//Mage::setIsDeveloperMode(true);//uncomment while developing
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
umask(0);
Mage::app();//instantiate the application
$productId = Mage::app()->getRequest()->getParam('product_id');
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
$block = Mage::app()->getLayout()->createBlock('catalog/product_view_type_configurable');
$block->setProduct($product);
$config = $block->getJsonConfig();
echo $config;
```

Now you should be able to get the config by calling `get_json_options.php?product_id=5`;